# changing category id in leboncoin scraper node js leboncoin-api

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape leboncoin so I searched for a tool to do it, I found this code when I run it the console gives me a 403 error and it logs the offer ids, but the problem that I can't change the category id:10 (Locations) to id:9 (ventes-immobiliers), so if someone can help me because I need this tool and I want just the offers id, so this is the code:

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const leboncoin = require('leboncoin-api');
const fs = require('fs');
const request = require('request');
const moment = require('moment');

/* Create config & credential files if they are missing
*/

if (!fs.existsSync('config.json'))
fs.writeFileSync('config.json', JSON.stringify({
"query": {
    "limit": 35,
    "offset": 0,
    "filters": {
        "category": {
            "id": "10"
        },
        "enums": {
            "ad_type": ["offer"],
            "furnished": ["1"],
            "real_estate_type": ["2"]
        },
        "location": {
            "area": {
                "lat": 48.10033,
                "lng": -1.79417,
                "radius": 1000
            }
        },
        "keywords": {},
        "ranges": {
            "price": {
                "min": 200
                
            }
        }
    }
},
"port": 1337,
"whitelist": [],
"blacklist": ['studette'],
"interval": 1000*60*3,
"countdown": 1000*10,
"timetolive": 60*60*3,
}), {flag: 'wx'});

if (!fs.existsSync('tokens.json'))
fs.writeFileSync('tokens.json', '[]', {flag: 'wx'});

if (!fs.existsSync('credentials.json')) {
fs.writeFileSync('credentials.json', JSON.stringify({
"type": '',
"project_id": '',
"private_key_id": '',
"private_key": '',
"client_email": '',
"client_id": '',
"auth_uri": '',
"token_uri": '',
"auth_provider_x509_cert_url": '',
"client_x509_cert_url": ''
}), {flag: 'wx'});
console.log("[critical] You need to add your own Firebase service account key file (see README.md #requirements)\n\n"
+"MORE INFO:\nhttps://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/*YOUR PROJECT*/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk");
process.exit();
}

/* Storage
*/

let persistence = {};

try {
persistence = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('persistence.json'));
} catch (error) {}

var config = require('./config.json') || {};
var tokens = persistence.tokens || [];
var offers = (persistence.offers || []).map(offer => {
offer.date = moment(offer.date);
return offer;
});

var offers_ids = persistence.offers_ids || [];
var avgSqrtPrice = getAvgSqrtPrice(offers);
var notified = null;

console.log("[tokens] "+offers_ids+" offers loaded");
console.log("[tokens] "+tokens.length+" tokens loaded");
console.log("[keywords]\n\t- Whitelist: "+config.whitelist.join(', ')+"\n\t- Blacklist: "+config.blacklist.join(', '));
console.log("\n");

/* Core (Express + Firebase Admin)
*/

admin.initializeApp({
credential: admin.credential.cert(require('./credentials.json')),
});

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
extended: true
}));

app.use(express.static('public'));

/* Routes
*/

app.post('/register', function (req, res) {
var token = req.body.token;

if (!token) {
console.error('[tokens] Invalid token');
return res.json({success: false, error: "Invalid token"});
}

if (tokens.indexOf(token) > -1) {
return res.json({success: true, message: "Already registered"});
}

tokens.push(token);

console.info('[tokens] Registered');
return res.json({success: true, message: "Registered"});
});

app.post('/unsubscribe', function (req, res) {
var token = req.body.token;

if (!token) {
console.error('[tokens] Invalid token');
return res.json({success: false, error: "Invalid token"});
}

var index = tokens.indexOf(token);

if (index === -1) {
console.error('[tokens] Not registered');
return res.json({success: true, message: "Not registered"});
}

tokens.splice(index, 1);

console.info('[tokens] Unsubscribed');
return res.json({success: true, message: "Unsubscribed"});
});

app.post('/offers', function (req, res) {
if (!offers.length)
return res.json({success: false, error: "Nothing to show"});

var id = req.body.id;
var query = req.body.query;

var base = offers.slice(0);

if (query) {
try {
    query = query.split("\n");

    query.forEach(condition => {
        base = base.filter(offer => {
            return eval(condition);
        })
    })
} catch (error) {
    return res.json({success: false, error: error.message});
}
}

if (!id) {
var items = base.slice(base.length - 15, base.length);
} else {
var index = null;

for (var i=0; i<base.length; i++) {
    if (id == base[i].id) {
        index = i;

        break;
    }
}

if (index === null)
    return res.json({success: false, error: "The provided id doesn't match with any active offers"});

var items = base.slice(Math.max(0, index - 15), index);
}

return res.json({success: true, offers: items, avgSqrtPrice: {
page: getAvgSqrtPrice(items),
total: avgSqrtPrice
}});
})

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
return res.sendFile(__dirname+'/public/app.html');
})

/* Startup
*/

app.listen(config.port, function () {
console.log("\nlistening on port "+config.port+"\n");
});

/* Listen to CLI inputs
*/

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

process.stdin.on('data', function(text) {
var path = text.trim().split(' ');

if (!path || !path.length)
return console.log("Invalid command\n");

var fn = path.splice(0, 1).toString();

switch (fn) {
case 'push':
    var n = parseInt(path[0]) || 0;

    sendNotifications(n);
break;
case 'get':
    getOffers();
break;
case 'list':
    list(offers);
break;
case 'flush':
    console.log('[tokens] Flush tokens');
    tokens = [];
break;
}
});

/* App related function
*/

var random_str = function() {
return Math.random().toString(36).substring();
}

var download = function(uri, path, callback){
if (fs.existsSync(path)) {

// File already exists
return typeof callback === 'function' && callback();

}

request.head(uri, function(err, res, body) {
if (err)
    return console.error(err);

request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path)).on('close', function() {
    typeof callback === 'function' && callback();
});
});
};

var getOffers = function() {
return new leboncoin.Search().run(null, config.query).then(data => {
if (!data.results) {
    console.log('[scraper] No results');

    return false;
}

const _offers = data.results.filter(offer => {
    if (offers_ids.indexOf(offer.id) !== -1) {
        return false;
    }

    if (config.whitelist.length && !(offer.title+' '+offer.description).toLowerCase().match(new RegExp(config.whitelist.join('|')))) {
        return false;
    }

    if (config.blacklist.length && (offer.title+' '+offer.description).toLowerCase().match(new RegExp(config.blacklist.join('|')))) {
        return false;
    }

    /* if (offers.filter(a => a.title == offer.title).length) {
        return false;
    } */

    return true;
});

if (_offers.length) {
    _offers.forEach(offer => {
        console.log('[scraper] Append offer #' + offer.id + ' (' + offer.title + ')');

        offer.date = moment(offer.date);

        offers_ids.push(offer.id);

        if (offer.images && offer.images.length) {
            offer.images.forEach((image, index) => {
                if (index > 0) {
                    return;
                }

                offer.images[index] = offer.id + '_' + index + '.jpg';
                download(image, __dirname+'/public/img/leboncoin/' + offer.images[index]);
            })
        }

        offers.push(offer);
    })

    avgSqrtPrice = getAvgSqrtPrice(offers);

    // 10 sec delay before sending the notifications to be sure that the images are up and everythings alright
    setTimeout(sendNotifications, config.countdown);
}
}).catch(error => {
throw new Error(error);
})
}

var sendNotifications = function(n) {
offers.sort(function(a, b) {
return a.date.diff(b.date);
});

if (!tokens.length)
return console.error('[push] No devices registered');

// list(offers, 16);

if (n && n > 0) {
console.log('[debug] Slice', offers.length - n, offers.length);
var data = offers.slice(offers.length - n, offers.length);

if (!data.length)
    return console.error('[push] Nothing to push ('+(offers.length - 1 - n)+' - '+offers.length+')');
} else {
if (notified === null)
    notified = offers.length - 1;

var data = offers.slice(notified, offers.length);

if (!data.length)
    return console.error('[push] Nothing new to push');

notified += data.length;
}

data.forEach(function(offer, indexMessage) {
admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, {
    data: {
        offer: JSON.stringify(offer)
    },
}, {
    timeToLive: config.timetolive || 60 * 60 * 3,
}).then(function(response) {
    var devices = 0;

    response.results.forEach(function(result, indexDevice) {
        if (result.error) {
            var code = result.error.errorInfo.code;

            console.error("\n[push] ERROR while sending push "+(indexMessage + 1)+"/"+data.length+" to device "+(indexDevice + 1)+"/"+tokens.length+"\n", "\t => \""+code+"\"\n");

            switch (code) {
                case 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered':
                    console.log('[tokens] Unsubscribing token');
                    tokens.splice(indexDevice, 1);
                break;
            }

            return;
        }

        devices++;
    });

    console.log('[push] 1 push (offer #'+offer.title+') sent to '+devices+' device'+(devices > 1 ? 's' : ''));
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('[push] ERROR', error);
});
})
}

function updatePersistence() {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
fs.writeFile('persistence.json', JSON.stringify({
    tokens: tokens,
    offers_ids: offers_ids,
    offers: offers,
}), err => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(`[persistence] Failed to write persistence.json\n\t`, err);
        return resolve(false);
    }

    return resolve(true);
});
});
}

function getAvgSqrtPrice(offers) {
const offersWithSquareAttribute = offers
.filter(offer => offer.attributes.square > 0);

if (!offersWithSquareAttribute.length) {
return 0;
}

return +(offersWithSquareAttribute.map(offer => offer.price / (offer.attributes.square)).reduce((a, b) => a + b) / offersWithSquareAttribute.length).toFixed(2);
}

var list = function(data, n, title) {
if (!data)
return;

var n = parseInt(n);

if (!title)
title = n ? "last "+Math.min(n, data.length)+" offers (out of "+data.length+")" : data.length+" offers";

console.log("\n[list] "+title+" :");
data.slice(n ? Math.max(0, data.length - n) : 0, data.length).forEach(function(offer) {
console.log("\t["+offer.id+"] "+offer.title+" ("+offer.price+", "+offer.date.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')+")");
});
console.log("\n");
}

getOffers();

// Delay in ms before getting new results
setInterval(getOffers, config.interval);

process.on('SIGINT', function() {
console.log('SIGINT');

Promise.all([updatePersistence()]).then(data => {
console.log('[server/exit] Goodbye')

process.exit();
}).catch(err => {
console.log(`[server/exit] Something went wrong when executing SIGINT script${err && err.message ? "\n\t" + err.message : ''}`);

process.exit();
})
});
```

Comment: 403 error is forbidden.  What’s the message that you are getting with it and where in you code is it occurring? It could be that you are being blocked when scraping the leboncoin website.  Some websites are smart about not allowing bots.  But there are also some pieces of this code for storing the data in firebase and you could be getting a 403 error there too if you haven’t set up the firebase app and authenticated properly.

Comment: This is the message showing in the console:

Comment: (node:5940) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Error: HTTP err : 403 Forbidden
    at C:\Users\amine\Desktop\push-leboncoin-master\push-leboncoin-master\server.js:326:9
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)

Comment: (node:5940) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: But it's work  and give me this ids but the problem that i want change category to "Ventes_immoboliers" with id:9  and when i change it not give me any ids like this:

Comment: [scraper] Append offer #1948511799 (Appartement type 2)
[scraper] Append offer #1948526538 (Chambre 1 pièce 14 m²)
[scraper] Append offer #1948218287 (T2 Moyenne durée)
[scraper] Append offer #1547027375 (Studio meublé 28m² Le Rheu)
[push] No devices registered
SIGINT

Comment: All this offers published today and its good but it's from "location" category's not "Ventes_immoboliers" and i can't change it,,,,,,, sorry for my little english.

Comment: @AMINEDAIEF from [the github readme](https://github.com/tdurieux/leboncoin-api#leboncoin-api--) of leboncoin-api : `leboncoin.fr is using DataDome to protect his API from library likes this one, currently all the requests are blocked`